# php call method of parent class doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm implementing a simple oop program and and something is not clear for me. Could someone explain why it doesn't work.

I have base class - **Animal** and subclass - **Dog**.

```
class Animal {
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $this->getName();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
    return $this->name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }
    public function print()
    {
        return "Dog name is  " . $this->getName();
    }
}
```

And `index.php` file where I test it.

```
$dog = new Dog('george');
echo $dog->getName();
echo $dog->print();
```

And output of this program is just `Dog name is`

Comment: When are you ever assigning `$name` to `$this->name`...? Hint: never.

Comment: `$this->name = $this->getName();` should be `$this->name = $name;` in the Animal constructor.

Comment: ^ Yes to @3x14159265's suggestion. If you use an IDE e.g. NetBeans it will warn you that `$name` is an unused parameter, which will help indicate there might be a problem.

Comment: (Incidentally, don't worry about the downvotes. Your question is well formatted and is detailed enough to answer - usually -4 indicates that the question is too broad or unclear).

Answer (score 2):

Well, look at what your constructor does:

```
public function __construct($name)
{
    // you assign to $this->name the return value of $this->getName()...which at that time, is null.
    $this->name = $this->getName();
}
```

You should use the `$name`parameter you pass to your constructor:

```
public function __construct($name)
{
    // okay!
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

Comment: if @moonwave99's answer is satisfactory, or one of the other ones is, could you please mark this with an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor of Animal is wrong. You are setting your variable with its getter... use the parameter of your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your derived class constructor sends the $name variable to the base class, but it never actually assigns it to the name property for either class.

Try

```
 public function __construct($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

And see if that changes your output.